# Is It Possible to Build and Distribute Simulator builds in AppCenter?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center-distribute

Our Automation QA team require a simulator build of the test app. Getting below error while building:

[image: Error Message]

Is It Possible to Build and Distribute Simulator builds in AppCenter?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have contacted Appcenter's Helpdesk. Following is their response :

You can build and distribute apps in App Center that can run on simulators and also on real devices.

**For Android**, if the build has been correctly signed, the APK can be installed on a real device and deployed to the Play Store. If the build has not been signed, the APK can be run on an emulator.

**For iOS simulator**, it is required for you to properly code sign the app. You can learn more about code signing for iOS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/code-signing
Then please see the steps below to set up code signing when building your app in App Center:

1. To sign the builds produced from a branch, enable code signing in the configuration pane and upload a provisioning profile (.mobileprovision) and a valid certificate (.p12), along with the password for the certificate.
   [image: Download Build]
2. Download the ipa file to install on a simulator.

Comment: Since the build for iOS device is built against a different architecture than for the Mac , how did the iPa run in Simulator?